# VBA End Function has a Syntax Error when running a Macro

Tags: vba, indexing

I'm new to VBA and am trying to print to a PDF, I can't get the last line to work because when I include the end section it says syntax error but when I take it out it says Expected: End Statement. I don't understand how both are possible.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Save_PDf()


 
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

  Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
  Dim PDSSaveCopy As Object
  

  If Not (avdoc Is Nothing) Then

    Set Pddoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc

    WasSaved = Pddoc.Save(PDSaveFull, "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages")

    
    Pddoc.Save PDSaveFull,  "E27" & "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages"" & Sh1.Cells(e + 28, 1).Value & ".pdf" End Function
   End with "e282"


End Sub
```

Comment: This part: `"E27" & "U:\Common\` looks problematic... why are you adding the string `E27` to the beginning of a path/filename? Are you expecting that to get the value in cell `E27`? Because it doesn't, and it doesn't belong where you put it.

Comment: The `e` variable is also a problem. Maybe we're supposed to be in a loop running through  the rows of column A in `Sh1` (where's `Sh1` defined?). There's *a lot* to unpack in this snippet, but to address the question as titled, `End Function` is a token that marks the last statement in a `Function` scope: when it runs, execution control flow returns to the caller, and any statement after it is illegal because it finds itself outside a procedure scope. You might have meant `Exit Function`, but you're in a `Sub`. I'm afraid this code isn't going to be salvageable without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this code, but you open an If statement without closing it with End If.  You also appear to have an End With statment with no opening With statement.  And then there's an End Function with no corresponding opening statement.  Not sure where you got the code from, but I would go back to it and check what you have copied.

Answer (score 0):

Every time we open a statement in vba we have to close it with end.
another best practice is to always have Indentation after statments like `sub` `if` `with` etc. - this will make your code more readable